# Accessing MTP mounted device in terminal

Tags: linux, fedora, mtp

`cd: /run/user/$UID/gvfs/mtp://%5Busb%3A001,010%5D/`

gives the error :

```
cd: no such file or directory: /run/user/1000/gvfs/mtp://%5Busb%3A001,010%5D/
```

Even though the device is mounted in the file manager and shows the same mtp path

I'd like to access it via terminal to able to copy data out of it as the File Manager just hangs when done via the GUI.

Distribution : Fedora 28

Comment: On debian, I installed  gvfs-daemons package and rebooted and it works now.

Answer (score 7):

cd to `/run/user/$UID/gvfs`, run `ls`.  You'll find the directory within there, without the %5B / %3A / %5D encodings.

Or just cd to it without the encodings

```
cd '/run/user/1000/gvfs/[usb:001,010]'
```

Comment: there is no directory there, `ls` returns empty

Comment: This answer isn't correct anymore, my `gvfs` directory is empty (Ubuntu 22)

21:38:45 with raleigh in /run/user/1000/gvfs at Z390-AORUS-PRO-WIFI 
➜ ls -lah
total 0
drwx------  2 raleigh raleigh  40 Oct 18 10:12 .
drwx------ 18 raleigh raleigh 560 Oct 18 15:13 ..

Comment: find the user id using "id" command

Answer (score 3):

On Debian 11 (Sid) with GNOME, I could browse the Android device in a graphical file manager but couldn't find the files anywhere using the terminal.

After I installed the `gvfs-fuse` package and rebooted, my Android device, when plugged, also became available in `/run/user/1000/gvfs/mtp\:host\=Name_of_my_device/`.

At last, I could use `rsync`!

Answer (score 1):

In my system I found that the `gio` command (from `glib2` package) can be used to explore and operate on mtp mount URIs.

For example:

> gio mount -l

will list all the known mountpoints locations

> gio list 'mtp://%5Busb%3A001,010%5D/'

will list the top level files at the that mount location path

> gio open 'mtp://%5Busb%3A001,010%5D/DCIM/Photo01.png'

will open the specified location with the corresponding mime handler defined in your system

Other file interactions commands that resemble shell commands exist: `remove`, `copy`, `move` and so on. See [man gio(1)](https://www.systutorials.com/docs/linux/man/1-gio/) for detailed explanation for each command or type the command `gio help` to see a list of them with short explanation.